# Prevent SSH access to instances launched from AWS AMI

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, coreos

We are trying to make a secured AMI for distribution to one of our customers (running Linux/CoreOS). Once our customer deploys our AMI, it is important that they cannot obtain shell access (e.g cannot SSH in).

On the surface, this seems like a very simple problem to solve: just make sure that only our keys are in the authorized_keys files. However, when our customer deploys our AMI, they are forced to provide their own key pair, and then the associated public key is inserted into the authorized_keys file on the box, enabling them to SSH into the box.

I know that Amazon makes the public key accessible (and user metadata) to the Host OS via HTTP on 169.254.169.254 (info here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html). Some sleuthing around the Internet and the CoreOS filesystem suggests that the /usr/bin/coreos-metadata actually accesses this IP, presumably for the keypair, but I can't figure out what is actually kicking off that executable or how to disable it. I even thought about removing executable privileges or remove it entirely, but that part of the filesystem is read-only on CoreOS (even to root).

Obviously the above behavior trumps whatever security measures we put in place. Is there anything we can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but create another user, give it sudo access for managing stuff, and revoke sudo access to the main account that AWS will be granting access to?

Comment: Another option - use the sshd `AllowUsers` directive to only allow ssh access via a user that's separate from the default built-in user.

Comment: Stop instance, detach volume, attach to a different instance, mount, modify authorized_keys, sudoers, etc., unmount, detach, reattach, restart... owned.  Or I can just make a snapshot of the volume if I just want to see the files.  Encryption? Well, the key has to be there somewhere.  I would assert that this has no technical solution, and it doesn't actually sound like a technical problem -- it sounds like a concern to be addressed contractually... or by running your software in your own VPC, peered with the customer's VPC, where they can access it securely with identical performance.

Comment: All really good points. I ended up making a new user, then using AllowUsers to disable the default user.

As an added layer of protection, I added a script to run on boot that blitzes the authorized_keys file of the default user and replaces it with a default key.

With these stated I understand that there is no way to fully protect a volume mounted into a foreign VPC. We do have contractual terms in place to prevent this, so those will have to suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cloud-init` is doing this.  Disable `sshd` from running (part of your AMI build), then have script code run that puts your keys in place under the login user (a different one is suggested), start up `ssh`.  I also suggest a different port number as an easy way to confirm you have things working right.

Comment: Another idea: make the cloud-init default user point to a non-existent account. You could also set the shell to /bin/false. http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html